# exploding a string with variable

Tags: php, variables, explode

I'm trying to manipulate a path to an image using php.
The path has a variable userdirectory in it, so i'm struggling with how to write this.

Ive used to do :

```
$texthtml = $content;
if (preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $texthtml, $image) ) {
$promopic = $image['src'];
}
```

to find if there is an image in my content and make a variable out of it. that works, but i need to alter my code to load image from a thumbnail directory for pageload reasons.

an image src looks like this : `"/uploads/userdirs/admin(variable)/image.jpg"`

But i want it to be this :

`"/uploads/userdirs/admin(variable)/mcith/mcith_image.jpg"`

adding a /mcith/ and a mcith_prefix to the image. 
I'm thinking exploding it, but i dont know how to do that with a variable path. Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Obligatory can't parse HTML with regex comment.

Comment: @Dotmister Please avoid comments like this. They serve only to create noise.

Comment: @Havihavi Do you want to *explode* (meaning break into parts resulting in an array) the string, or merely *replace* some of its content to result in a new string?

Comment: i thought of using str_replace or explode to get a new string with the desired value. but i wouldnt know how to, as the /admin/ path is variable

Comment: check out parse_url, http://ca3.php.net/parse_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this many different ways, but I would probably use [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) for this:

```
$path = pathinfo($promopic);
$thumb = $path['dirname'] . '/mcith/mcith_' . $path['basename'];
```

Comment: Worked great! i gotta read up on pathinfo. awesome stuff, thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

very simple version, could use improvement

```
preg_replace('/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,4})$/', '/mcith/mcith_$1', '/uploads/userdirs/admin(variable)/image.jpg');
```