# alter all images in a string

Tags: php, string

I'm using this line to change all images in my `$comments` string:

```
$comments = preg_replace("{<img\\s*(.*?)src=('.*?'|\".*?\"|[^\\s]+)(.*?)\\s*/?>}ims", '<a class ="gallery"rel="'.$pagelink.'"href=$2><img $1src=$2 $3 name= $2 $3  /></a>', $comments);
```

This works like a charm, it wraps it in `<a>` and adds some stuff. Now I need to alter the src path.

I want to add `"mcith/mcith_"` to every image in a string. i had a look at dom functions, but that didn't really seem to do the trick.

An image path looks like this: "/uploads/userdirs/admin(variable dir changes from user to user)/image.jpeg"

I want it to be this: "/uploads/userdirs/admin/mcith/mcith_image.jpeg"

On the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246534/exploding-a-string-with-variable) I got the answer using pathinfo, so I tried doing this:

```
if (preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $comments, $image) ) {
   $imagedir = $image['src'];
   $pathchange = pathinfo($imagedir);
   $comments = $pathchange['dirname'] . '/mcith/mcith_' . $pathchange['basename'];
}
```

But that doesn't work as I want it to as it messes up my entire string instead, text and all.
I think the solution is in the preg_replace line, but can't figure out how to add stuff to the src on that line.

Comment: [I wouldn't use RegEx to parse HTML.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/871050)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
<?php
$comment = '<img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin-something/image.jpeg" />
<div>text</div>
<img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin-another/coffee.png" />
';
$comment = preg_replace('@(<img.+src=[\'"]/uploads/userdirs/admin)(?:.*?/)(.+?)\.(.+?)([\'"].*?>)@i', '$1/mcith/mcith_$2.$3$4', $comment);
echo $comment;
```

See if it helps. Try online: http://codepad.org/TT9rH6IX

Comment: ended up using this modified line from your reply : 
`$comments = (preg_replace('@(<img.+src=[\'"]/uploads/userdirs/admin)(?:.*?/)(.+?)\.(.+?)([\'"].*?>)@i', '<a class="gallery" rel="'.$pagelink.'" href=/uploads/userdirs/'.$who.'/$2.$3>$1/mcith/mcith_$2.$3$4</a>', $comments));
`
Thanks a bunch for all replies and good help =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution...Hope this will help you

```
    if(preg_match_all('/(<img[^>]*>)/Ui', $comments, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){ //loop through all img tags 
        $shiftOffset = 0;
        for($i=0; $i<count($match[1]); $i++){  //loop to execute no.of times img tag found
        if($i){ // do not change offset for single or first occurence
                $shiftOffset += substr_count($match[1][$i-1][0], "<img ");  //count the img tag
                $match[1][$i][1] += $shiftOffset;
               }
        $sub = "form your new img src that is to replaced for old img src"; 
        $comments = str_replace($match[1][$i][0],$sub,$comments); //change the original img tag with our img tag
       }
   }
```